# PHP failed to load string from other function as parameter

Tags: php

```js
 public function test_passing_string() {
   $this - > load - > model(array('registration/Registration_model', 'Jawaban_lab_model'));
   $registration = new Registration_model();
   $jawaban_lab = new Jawaban_lab_model();
   $id = "kuda4";

   $jawaban_lab - > load($id); //load jawaban_lab from id 
   $manualy_written_registration_number = "REG/FM/130102-0001";

   echo "registration number from jawaban_lab->registration_number : ".$jawaban_lab - > registration_number
     .
   "<br> registration number from manualy_written_registration_number : ".$manualy_written_registration_number;

   //$registration->load($jawaban_lab->registration_number);
   $registration - > load($manualy_written_registration_number);

   echo "<br> patient id : ".json_encode($registration - > PatientID);
 }
```

Before go to the question, I will explain my code.

On `test_passing_string()` function, I call 2 model, and create object for each model there are $registration and `$jawaban_lab`.

To load data from model I create a `load()` function. `load()` has two parameters: `column_value` and `column_name`. The default value for `column_name` is that model's Primary Key.

**BUT**

The problem comes from

> $registration->load($jawaban_lab->registration_number);

I can't retrieve any $registration object data, then I test it by passing the value manually by write this:

> $manualy_written_registration_number = "REG/FM/130102-0001";
>   $registration - > load($manualy_written_registration_number);

And the result appear, doesn't that mean my `load()` function is fine?

Then I check value inside `$jawaban_lab->registration_number` by `echo`ing it, surprisingly it display same value as my `$manualy_written_registration_number` variable.

This is screenshoot in my browser when I run `test_passing_string()` function:

**Using $manualy_written_registration_number value**
[image]

**Using $jawaban_lab->registration_number value**
[image]

Why can't I use the value from
 `$jawaban_lab->registration_number` even though it has the same value as
 my manually writen registraiton number?

```
   public function load($column_value, $column_name = NULL) {
        $query = NULL;
        if ($column_name != NULL) {
            // using custom column.
            $query = $this->dbs->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array(
                $column_name => $column_value
            ));
        } else {
            // using column primary key .
            $query = $this->dbs->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array(
                $this::DB_TABLE_PK => $column_value
            ));
        }
        if ($query->row()) {
            $this->populate($query->row());
        }
    }
```

I use multiple database using CodeIgniter 3, registration_model from SQL server and jawaban_lab from MySQL, jawaban lab have column registration_number to store registration_model primary key

#### var_dump

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: @rlanvin thanks rlanvin, I added the question

Comment: May be what you are passing is wrong or its same value...

Comment: try assiging your value to a variable and then pass that variable to function as parameter.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju what do you mean by "its same value"?, or maybe you have tools that you usually use for php problems?

Comment: First, use `var_dump` instead of echo, maybe one value as some space at the end or something that you don't see. Second, you're not telling us the full story, I have no idea what `load` method does, the problem might be elsewhere. And finally, what's with the ` - > ` syntax in your code snippet? It's invalid.

Comment: @Akshay the output is the same as "using $jawaban_lab->registration_number value" screenshoot

Comment: In model check if u have hardcoded anything...  for that ur getting same response....

Comment: @rlanvin var_dump and load() already added. for - > is the same with ->, that happend because i paste my code in javascript section

Comment: Your var_dump is completely useless right now. `var_dump($jawaban_lab->registration_number)` and `var_dump($manualy_written_registration_number)` separately.

Comment: @rlanvin sorry, this is the result string(18) "REG/FM/130102-0001" string(18) "REG/FM/130102-0001"

Comment: Ok, now you need to add debug code in your `load` method to see what the query looks like in both cases.

Comment: @rlanvin , thanks for still with me, what tools i should use?, i only know firebug

Comment: Use `var_dump` to see that the query looks like (hopefully there is a method to the get the SQL that is being generated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to rlanvin and Nirajan N Raju

from rlanvin's comment, i find out the problem is come from codeigniter's query helper, because when i enable codeigniter profiling sql server query return "SELECT CASE WHEN (@@OPTIONS | 256) = @@OPTIONS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS qi"

so i think codeigniter might be cannot generate query so i create the query manually

i change

```
 public function load($column_value, $column_name = NULL) {
    $query = NULL;
    if ($column_name != NULL) {
        // using custom column.
        $query = $this->dbs->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array(
            $column_name => $column_value
        ));
    } else {
        // using column primary key .
        $query = $this->dbs->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array(
            $this::DB_TABLE_PK => $column_value
        ));
    }
    if ($query->row()) {
        $this->populate($query->row());
    }
}
```

to this

```
 public function load($column_value, $column_name = NULL) {
    $query = NULL;
    if ($column_name != NULL) {
            $query = $this->dbs->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this::DB_TABLE . " WHERE " . $column_name . " LIKE '" . trim($column_value) . "'");
        } else {
            $query = $this->dbs->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this::DB_TABLE . " WHERE " . $this::DB_TABLE_PK . " LIKE '" . trim($column_value) . "'");
        }
    if ($query->row()) {
        $this->populate($query->row());
    }
}
```